# strange behaviour with facebook page tab

Tags: ajax, facebook, hash

i noticed a strange behaviour of facebook page tab applications, using internet explorer (i tested this only on ie8... with other browser this problem is not present).

If i put javascript code, or background sound in my application, when i goes out from page tab, my application is still running (for example sounds, or javascript activity)...

To show you the issue, i created a page....

Log in into facebook and goes to this page.

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=252545344807399&sk=app_252545344807399

Don't click like button or anything... you can see a javascript alert each 5 seconds...

next, click on the top facebook logo. You will be redirected to your facebook home, but the url has an hash symbol, because it loads content in ajax.

Wait 5 seconds and tell me if you are still receiving javascript alert from my application in background.

Tell me please if you experience this problem.

Thanks in advance.
Giuseppe
(sorry for bad english)

.

Comment: I don't get **any** alerts. all i get is this inside your iframe :`
<fb:fbml version="1.1">
aqwqwqw</fb:fbml>`

Comment: sorry, this output is from ssl version... i updated this page too. retry please.

Comment: alright - i can confirm the behavior you described.  Can you post some code? how are you executing the alerts?

Comment: this is the step to reproduce. Create application. use Page Tab URL. In html put this: <script> setInterval("alert('test alert');",5000); </script> Create a facebook page. Go to application and add to your page. Visit your page, and go to related tab. Wait 5 seconds and you can see the alert. Now click on top facebook logo... with IE, the url has an hash sign. You should see the alert each 5 seconds even if you are not in your app.

Comment: Wow... **weird** behavior indeed.  I think you should definatly report this to facebook.  [Here is a link to the bug reporter](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).  You can open a bug and I'll confirm that it is reproducible...

Comment: thanks... 
done :)
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/208209735922797